# How to speed up sqlite search through over 500,000 rows of international characters

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table called search_terms with a column called term with a type of TEXT.  There is also a column called id and popularity.  The term contains international characters as well as ASCII characters. (Japanese and English)

I'm trying to search through this table quickly using sqlite.  Unfortunately, searches are taking well over 5 seconds.  I search with something similar to:

```
SELECT id from search_terms where term LIKE 'ka%' order by popularity
```

I understand sqlite LIKE operator is slow due to it not taking advantage of indexes (bummer).  Also, FTS can't help me here because I'm not searching for full words.  It starts with the first letter and the search may continue (using a live search paradigm).

Other things to note.  The data in the database is static.  It won't change.  I can add tables to speed things up, possibly, I'd just like some suggestions.  This is heading into an embedded device, so it needs to be as quick as possible.  Assume space is not an issue.

Comment: Does using regular comparisons help?  That is, on DB2, using `WHERE term >= 'ka' AND term < 'kb'` produces the equivalent functionality.  Not sure what you'd have to do with sort sequences for the kana, though.  I'm assuming that SQLite doesn't support recursive CTEs, or you could possibly (pre) split your data to ids (sort of a prefix tree, I guess), although this may not perform any better...

Answer (score 1):

If is it possible, use indexes.

```
create clustered index ix1 on TABLE (term)
```

or

```
create nonclustered index ix1 on TABLE (term)
```

Try It.

Tiz

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, [SQLite does use an index for LIKE](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#like_opt). But you need to create an index of course.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite FTS does support prefix searches:

```
MATCH 'ka*'
```

instead of

```
LIKE 'ka%'
```

assuming the table is changed to an FTS table.